# How to pass NgModelController to directive controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Can i pass NgModelController to directive controller? That's required so i can assign values to model in controller.

This example does not work:

```
   angular
     .module('directives.selectBox', [])
     .directive('selectBox', selectBox);  

    function selectBox() {
        return {
          restrict   : 'E',
          require    : 'ngModel',
          scope      : {
             list     : '=',
          },
          replace     : true,
          templateUrl : 'common/directives/selectBox/selectBox.html',
          controller :  SelectBoxController,
        };
    }  
    function SelectBoxController(ngModel) {
       ngModel.$setViewValue(10); // ???
    }
```

Comment: You can inject it in link function, not the controller.

Comment: Using directives syntax "controller as".This technique turns bad in this case?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları ngModel cannot be injected, it is just available as argument in the link function, even if you do not use it it is still available in the link function as argument when you require ngModel. It is different from dependency injection.

Comment: Can some one create a fiddle for the same? I am a little confused with the model part

Answer (score 27):

Pretty simple actually, what you need to do is to get access to the element by injecting `$element` into your controller and then calling the `.controller()` function on it.

```
angular
   .module('directives.selectBox', [])
   .directive('selectBox', selectBox);  

function selectBox() {
    return {
      restrict   : 'E',
      require    : 'ngModel',
      scope      : {
         list     : '=',
      },
      replace     : true,
      templateUrl : 'common/directives/selectBox/selectBox.html',
      controller :  SelectBoxController,
    };
}  
function SelectBoxController($element) {
   var ngModel = $element.controller('ngModel');
   ngModel.$setViewValue(10); // ???
}
```

#### Angular 1.5 update

Note that in AngularJS 1.5 the new `component()` function was added in addition to the existing `directive()` function. This function takes a configuratoin object as second parameter that allows you to directly specify the required controllers, which will then be bound to the component's controller.

Below the same example again, but as component.

```
angular
   .module('directives.selectBox', [])
   .component('selectBox', 
        {
            controller: SelectBoxController,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl : 'common/directives/selectBox/selectBox.html',
            bindings: {
                list: '=' // though '<' would be better
            }, 
            require: {
                ngModel: '='
            },
            // replace: true ==> No longer possible with component
        }
    );  

function SelectBoxController($element) {

    $onInit() {
        // This function is called automatically whenever the controller is ready
        this.ngModel.$setViewValue(10); // ???
    }
}
```

I hope I typed it out ok, this tiny textarea is hardly an IDE :)

Comment: This sounds like a pretty simple solution. I was just thinking if it would not be a better idea to use events to handle inter controller communication?

Comment: When talking about true inter-controller communication (between separate controllers that is) I would agree that events or a service should be used. In this case however I feel the controller is just part of the directive and thus having a strong tie between the directive creation function and it's controller is not a problem.

Comment: be aware that the require binding is not currently available for `angular.component()`s created using the angular-component polyfill for angular versions under 1.5.x

Answer (score 0):

First I note your controller is not declared in the module, so it is not called. (might also want to rename it so it's not confusing

```
angular
     .module('directives.selectBox', [])
     .controller('SelectBoxController',SelectBoxController)
     .directive('selectBox', selectBox);
```

The directive takes the ng-model. then you can access it using $scope.ngModel within the link function of the directive.

```
function selectBox() {
        return {
          restrict   : 'E',
          require    : 'ngModel',
          scope      : {
             list     : '=',
          },
          replace     : true,
          templateUrl : 'common/directives/selectBox/selectBox.html',
          controller :  SelectBoxController,
          link: function($scope, $element, $attr, ngModel) {

                $scope.ngModel.$setViewValue(10);
           }
        };
```

here the controller is not even needed actually.
Note that you don't necessarily need ngModel, you are passing 'list' as a 2 way binding param here already, so if you want to pass another argument as a parameters, just pass it like your 'list' param in the isolated scope.
You should also not be assigning directly to the ng-model or param you pass, but rather to a 'child' element of the object, or you'll see weird behavior as your local object will shadow the original object of the parent scope.

So you may pass 'model.list' as the 'list' param, and then modify 'list' in the local scope which will modify 'model.list' in the parent scope.
if you pass 'list' and modify it in the local scope, it will be overriding the list in the parent scope and probably not get your the 2-way binding you expect.

Comment: Not working. console.log($scope.ngModel) -> undefined

Comment: "your controller is not declared in the module, so it is not called" this is incorrect.  If you look at the documentation for `$compile` you'll see that this can be a constructor function for a controller to the directive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to affect only model value, $parse method best suit for you because it provides common way to comminicate with outer scope and write code, which does not depends on new scope creation.

```
angular.directive('selectBox', function($parse){
    return {
       // your directive stuff
       link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
           var angularVarSetter = $parse(iAttrs.ngModel).assign;
           // in case of no own scope.
           angularVarSetter(scope, 100500);
           // in case of new scope
           angularVarSetter(scope.$parent, 100500);
       }
    };
});
```