# how can I access ngModel from directive controller

Tags: directive, angularjs-ng-model, controlleras

```
function prMySelects() {
  var ddo = {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    require: '?ngModel',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    controller: prMySelectsController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true
  };
  return ddo;
}

function prMySelectsController($locale) {
   ...
}
```

I need do some checks inside directive controller and set ngModel.$setValidity('some', false), but getting `ngModel is not defined` error. Injecting ngModel didn't help...

PS I know that I can access it in `link`, but is it possible to reach ngModel controller in directive `controller`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass NgModelController to directive controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786854/how-to-pass-ngmodelcontroller-to-directive-controller)

Answer (score 1):

This sort of functionality is best done inside the link function for a directive.

```
function prMySelects() {
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       require: '?ngModel',
       link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
          scope.theModel = ngModel;
       },
       controller: function() {
           var vm = this;
            vm.theModel.$setViewValue...
       }
    }
}
```

In this case, your are actually getting a hook into the ngModel controller and its not required that you actually specifiy it on the scope.

Comment: yes, I know that I can access it in `link`, but is it possible to reach ngModel controller in directive `controller`?